# Adding H2 Under H1 in categories pages from Magento 2 backend

Tags: php, xml, magento2, magento-2.3

I am working on Meta module and wondering how to add additional text field in

> Magento Backend > Catalog > categories > Search Engine Optimization > Custom Heading H2

and add it after H1 in frontend layout when visiting categories page. Right now there is H1 heading by default in theme that appears and show the Category name as H1, and i want to add custom H2 for each category from magento backend based on entry written on categories at backend level.

Comment: If anyone still needs this, check this other answer on adding custom H1 and H2 to Magento 2 category: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/336769/93529